# The type fuzzydl.exception.InconsistentOntologyException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, eclipse-neon

I' m a beginner in JAVA and I'm developing a web application on Eclipse Neon, using Apache Tomcat. I write   search.jsp file and this is a small part:

```
                <%@page import="cercaPattern.*, searchPattern.*, fuzzydl.exception.*,fuzzydl.parser.*"%>
                <%
                Cerca ricerca = new Cerca();
                try
                {

                    ricerca.cercaPattern();
                    Search cerca = new Search();
                    cerca.cercaPattrn();
                }

                catch (InconsistentOntologyException exc)
                {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (FuzzyOntologyException exc)
                {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (ParseException exc)
                {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
```

However I think that the imports of fuzzydl.exception.* and fuzzydl.parser.* are not needed.
I have this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 58 in the jsp file: /search.jsp The type
fuzzydl.exception.InconsistentOntologyException cannot be resolved. It
is indirectly referenced from required .class files 55:                     try 56:
                    { 57:                        58:                        ricerca.cercaPattern(); 59:                         Search cerca = new Search(); 60:                        cerca.cercaPattrn(); 61:                    }


An error occurred at line: 58 in the jsp file: /search.jsp The type
fuzzydl.exception.FuzzyOntologyException cannot be resolved. It is
indirectly referenced from required .class files 55:                    try 56:
                    { 57:                        58:                        ricerca.cercaPattern(); 59:                         Search cerca = new Search(); 60:                        cerca.cercaPattrn(); 61:                    }


An error occurred at line: 58 in the jsp file: /search.jsp The type
fuzzydl.parser.ParseException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
referenced from required .class files 55:                   try 56:                     { 57:
                         58:                        ricerca.cercaPattern(); 59:                         Search cerca = new Search(); 60:                        cerca.cercaPattrn(); 61:                    }


An error occurred at line: 58 in the jsp file: /search.jsp The method
cercaPattern() from the type Cerca refers to the missing type
ParseException 55:                  try 56:                     { 57:                        58:
                        ricerca.cercaPattern(); 59:                         Search cerca = new Search(); 60:                        cerca.cercaPattrn(); 61:                    }


An error occurred at line: 63 in the jsp file: /search.jsp
InconsistentOntologyException cannot be resolved to a type 60:
                        cerca.cercaPattrn(); 61:                    } 62:                    63:                    catch (InconsistentOntologyException exc) 64:                   { 65:
                        exc.printStackTrace(); 66:                  }


An error occurred at line: 67 in the jsp file: /search.jsp
FuzzyOntologyException cannot be resolved to a type 64:                     { 65:
                        exc.printStackTrace(); 66:                  } 67:                   catch (FuzzyOntologyException exc) 68:                  { 69:
                        exc.printStackTrace(); 70:                  }


An error occurred at line: 71 in the jsp file: /search.jsp
ParseException cannot be resolved to a type 68:                     { 69:
                        exc.printStackTrace(); 70:                  } 71:                   catch (ParseException exc) 72:                  { 73:                       exc.printStackTrace(); 74:                  }


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:212)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I don' t understand this, because I add an exernal FuzzyDL.jar file that contains the 2 packages that contain the 3 file .class, as in image:

[image]

and the code of Cerca.java is this:

```
package searchPattern;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import fuzzydl.*;
import fuzzydl.exception.*;
import fuzzydl.milp.*;
import fuzzydl.parser.*;
import fuzzydl.util.*;

import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAnnotation;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLEntity;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLIndividual;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLLiteral;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.PrefixManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.DefaultPrefixManager;

public class Cerca
{
    public void cercaPattern () throws IOException, OWLOntologyCreationException, ParseException, FuzzyOntologyException, InconsistentOntologyException
    {
        System.out.println("palo0");
        ConfigReader.loadParameters("CONFIG", new String[0]);
        System.out.println("palo1");
        Parser parser = new Parser(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Salvatore\\workspace\\progetto_per_ISA\\WebContent\\WEB-INF\\architecturalpatterns2.txt"));
        System.out.println("palo2");
        parser.Start();
        System.out.println("palo3");
        KnowledgeBase kb = Parser.getKB("C:\\Users\\Salvatore\\workspace\\progetto_per_ISA\\WebContent\\WEB-INF\\architecturalpatterns.owl");
        System.out.println("palo4");
        kb.saveToFile("C:\\Users\\Salvatore\\workspace\\progetto_per_ISA\\WebContent\\WEB-INF\\ontologyoutput.txt");
        System.out.println("palo5");
    }
}
```

Furthermore, Console in Eclipse don' t show the string "palo0" and others strings contained in Cerca.java.

Comment: Try cleaning your project, most of the time in my case it solves the issue.

Comment: Is this `cerca.cercaPattrn();` written correctly?

Comment: I tried to clean project, but there is the same problem.Other suggestions?